# Matrix A sandwiched between two orthonormal vectors is just an element of A? Need help with proof.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, orthonormal

Our instructor wrote the following without doing a proof and I never got to ask him how he derived it.

Given an $n\times n$ Matrix $A$ and an orthonormal set of basis column vectors $\{\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, ..., \mathbf{v}_n\}$ then
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{v}_a^\intercal \mathbf{A} \, \mathbf{v}_b &= A_{ab}
\end{align*}
$$

I can see this for the standard basis but what about any general orthonormal basis? Any hints greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is $\mathbf{A}_{ab}$?

Comment: the element of $\mathbf{A}$ that is on row $a$, col $b$

Comment: If you write out $v_b$ and $v_a$ in terms of a general orthonormal basis and do the multiplication, I think you will find the answer.

Comment: Yeah I know it is trivial with the general orthonormal basis like $v_1=(1 0 0 ...0), v_2=(0 1 0...0)$ etc. But our professor was saying it is true for any orthonormal basis.

Comment: If this is true for any matrix $A$, take $A=\mathbf{v}_1\mathbf{v}_2^T$, for example, and apply the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is basically saying that $V^TAV=A$ for any orthogonal matrix $V$. It is obviously false. If it were true then for any symmetric matrix $S$ we could perform diagonalization $D=V^TSV=S$ and conclude that any symmetric matrix were diagonal. The only matrix that satisfies this rule for all $V$ is a scalar multiple of identity (can be shown via [Schur triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition), for example).

P.S. Fix an ON basis $\{v_k\}$ for which it is true. Then taking $A=v_iv_j^T$ and applying the rule we get that the basis must be the standard one.

Comment: Thanks that makes much more sense! Don't know why our instructor was saying this then or I just misunderstood him.

Comment: @Wikkyd Perhaps it was meant to be the standard basis.